# C# Program ignore .Net

Tags: c#

I have a C# program, and it requires .Net 4.5. When I try to run the program on a system that doesn't have .Net 4.5 it gives a warning and asks the user to download it. In my program, it checks for for .Net 4.5 and if it's not there goes and downloads it. The problem is that if you ignore the warning, the program closes. Is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: What do you want it to do, not ask and just close?

Comment: Chicken, meet egg... If you're writing a program targeting .Net 4.5 then you need to have .Net 4.5 installed. It's silly to make your .Net 4.5 program check to see if the user has .Net 4.5 installed if it can't run in the first place...

Comment: Do you want to prevent program closing until download is completed?

Comment: Next time your fuel gauge is on low and that little light starts flashing just ignore the warning and post a question on caroveflow.com how to bypass the warning instead...

Answer (score 8):

> Is there a way to bypass this?

No point in by passing it.

Even if you bypass it, you can't really do anything with your program because it requires .Net 4.5.

**EDIT**

Do you really need .Net framework 4.5? or did you just went with the default target framework in Visual Studio 2012. You may [change that that to .Net 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb398202.aspx) (or .Net 3.5, which would be [available with Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164495/windows-7-default-net-framework)) if you are not using any feature from .Net 4.5.

Answer (score 3):

I sugest to create a MSI installer to deploy your program. In a such installer you can check some prerequisites like the presence of the .NET 4.5 and take many other possible actions.

Comment: He already has that, by the sound of it.

Comment: @Servy I disagree, MSI Installers have no .NET requirement, the problem the OP has is his own installer that will install .NET requires .NET itself.

Comment: Most of the installer tools have support to generate MSI files that check for the presence of different .NET versions.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Ah, I was reading the OP as if the program only closes if you specifically choose not to download the .NET framework, rather than that he's unable to have his program download it.  You're right.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can hack the executble PE Header info and Change the .Net version to the desired version if you are lucky the application will works without problem but if the applcation call any function(**only exist in .Net 4.5 Framework**) and  does not exist in the current framework the application will Crash!

Important info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx

Thanks

Comment: @axrwkr No I have changed some other header info but not the .Net version. theoretically shall not be a problem? any objection? I recommend you to use those tools if you wana to try it: http://www.hiew.ru/ and http://www.heaventools.de/overview.htm